# Unauthorized for Creating issue by cURL command using JIRA REST API

Tags: curl, jira-rest-java-api

I need to automate the creation of issues in jira, I wrote this in the command line

C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl.exe -D- -u fred:fred -X POST --data @C:\send.json -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://jira.XXXX:8080/rest/api/2/issu/

where send.json contains the data to be inserted but I always receive http/1.1 401 Unauthorized error

Can anyone help me through this unauthorization?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write curl.exe just write :

> curl -D- -H "Authorization: Basic *[encodedusernamepassword here]*" -X POST --data @json.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://abc.xyz.org/jira/rest/api/latest/issue"

8080 is not required in the url..
create an authorization key :
look for the documentation here :
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Basic+Authentication